# Find a file and return after the first match in a perl script

Tags: perl, find

I am using the find from perl. It works but I want to return (exit) from subrutine wanted after a first match is found, I would like to stop the find. I put the return but it doesn't work.
Here is my code:

```
find(\&wanted, $dir);

sub wanted {
    print "Found it $File::Find::dir/$_\n" if /$file/i; 
        $found_file = "$File::Find::dir/$_";  
        return "$File::Find::dir/$_";
}

print $found_file;
```

$dir is the directory I am searching in and $file is the file I need.

Where should I put the returi in the sub wanted. I am new to perl, any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I've tryed as you suggested but it still won't stop after the first find:  <print "Found it $File::Find::dir/$_\n" if /$file/;
        $global_prune = 1 if /$file/;
        return if $global_prune;>

Comment: <
        print "Found it $File::Find::dir/$_\n" if /$file/;
        $global_prune = 1 if /$file/;
        return if $global_prune;>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`File::Find` is a wacky module. It almost requires you code your entire program inside the `wanted` section. If you don't want to do this, you are usually required to use some sort of badly scoped variable which makes things look ugly. Plus, it uses a separate subroutine that makes the code harder to follow.

The problem is that `File::Find` isn't object oriented. If it was, you could fetch the files in a loop using a method, and when you get the file you want, you can leave the loop.

Fortunately, there's already a [File::Find::Object](https://metacpan.org/pod/File%3a%3aFind%3a%3aObject) which is an object oriented version of `File::Find`.

```
sub find_file {
    my @directories = @_;
    my $dir_tree = File::Find::Object->new( @directories );

    while ( my $file = $dir_tree->next ) {
      next unless ... # Code used to determine if file is what you want
      return $file
    }
    return;   #Nothing found
}
```

The interface is clean and easy to understand. It's how `File::Find` should work. I don't know why it's not a standard distribution module.

---

The main problem with `File::Find` is that it's old (From the Perl 3.x) days, and was never really intended to be a *module*. It was made to work with the [find2perl](http://perldoc.perl.org/find2perl.html) program that still comes with Perl distributions. Want to see something ugly and scary? Run a find query through `find2perl` and see the results. This is what old Perl code use to look like.